# Change Liststyle in moderncv - cvitemlist

Tags: pdftex, itemize, moderncv

I am using this [Template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Curriculum_Vitae#europecv) (moderncv section) for my cv.

There is one thing that i would like to change. I have a section Skills where I am listing the languages that i know:

[image]

I want change the default style from "o" that are not centered and filled

to small black dots that are filled and centered. Does someone of you know how this can be done?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.76]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{Test}
\familyname{Tester}
\address{Street}{City} 
\mobile{Number} 
\email{Email} 


\begin{document}

\section{Skills}

\cvitem{Language}{}
% Start enumeration
\cvlistitem{German: native}  
\cvlistitem{English: ....}
\cvlistitem{Spanish: ....}

\cvitem{Program languages}{}
% Start enumeration
\cvlistitem{C++: ....}  
\cvlistitem{Java: ...}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}

%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.76]{geometry}

%% Personal data
\firstname{Test}
\familyname{Tester}
\address{Street}{City} 
\mobile{Number} 
\email{Email} 

\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{color1}{\rmfamily\textbullet}}

\begin{document}

\section{Skills}

\cvitem{Language}{}
% Start enumeration
\cvlistitem{German: native}  
\cvlistitem{English: ....}
\cvlistitem{Spanish: ....}

\cvitem{Program languages}{}
% Start enumeration
\cvlistitem{C++: ....}  
\cvlistitem{Java: ...}


\end{document}
```